# Avoid making actual Rest call in RestTemplate Junit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mocking, spring-boot-test

Below is my EmployeeService using RestTemplate for which i have written Junit which is working .But the problem is my JUNIT is making an actual call to Rest end point.How can i avoid making an actual rest call?

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    
    
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public Employee getEmployee(String id) {
    ResponseEntity resp = 
          restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/employee/" + id, Employee.class);
        
    return resp.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK ? resp.getBody() : null;
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmployeeServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeService empService = new EmployeeService();

    @Test
    public void givenMockingIsDoneByMockito_whenGetIsCalled_shouldReturnMockedObject() {
        Employee emp = new Employee(“E001”, "Eric Simmons");
        Mockito
          .when(restTemplate.getForEntity(
            “http://localhost:8080/employee/E001”, Employee.class))
          .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(emp, HttpStatus.OK));
 
        Employee employee = empService.getEmployee(id); **// Actual call happens .How to avoid it.**
        Assert.assertEquals(emp, employee);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are initializing the Service entity, try @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeService empService;;

Comment: it still makes an actual call.I have just modified the my EmployeeService code.I am not autowiring the RestTemplate object

Comment: Remove `new EmployeeService`. Also you shouldn't create a new `RestTemplate` but inject it using Spring in your service (use the `RestTemplateBuilder` in an `@Bean` method to create one).

Comment: @M.Deinum solution is working now.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an explicit new RestTemplate();

So, you can not mock it.

An approach would be creating a @Component that performs the actual call.

```
@Component
public class MyHttpClient {

public ResponseEntity callingMethod(RestTemplate restTemplate, String id) {
restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/employee/" + id, Employee.class);
}
}
```

So, you call it from the class

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

@Autowired
private myHttpClient MyHttpClient;    
    
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public Employee getEmployee(String id) {
        ResponseEntity resp = myHttpClient.callingMethod(restTemplate, id);
...
    }
}
```

From the test you mock the new class and you when it:

```
@Mock
private MyHttpClientMock myHttpClientMock;

when(myHttpClientMock.callingMethod(Mockito.<RestTemplate> any()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Irrelevant code.You probably  hasn't seen  my complete code

Comment: What makes you think that? Maybe if you give it a try you'll find it useful

Comment: because you have nor provided complete code .Its missing the actual issue where i make the actual call to the method
`Employee employee = empService.getEmployee(id)`

Comment: This call remains the same. You don't have to change it. I've narrowed to the changes for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: i get NPE .doesnt work.please post complete testable code

Answer (score 0):

you need to change test to mock

```
public Employee getEmployee(String id)
```

by doing

```
doReturn(emp).when(empService).getEmployee(1);//or a wild card
```